# i.MX7D board detected as Android ADB Interface but adb devices does not show the device

Tags: android, android-things

I recently got an Android Thing kit with NXP i.MX7D board. I tried to follow the instruction to flash the board with Android and found a glitch which I have not found a solution yet.

I'm running Windows 10 PC and when I plugged the board [Devices Manager detected the device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/008TY.png) as Android ADB Interface.

[image]

But when I tried to check the command line and use adb devices, [the adb does not detect any device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAJAM.png).

[image]

Is there any extra software or plug-ins which I need to install to develop Android Things on Windows?

[update]: I managed to change the driver to Google's driver, but still not detected.

I tried plugging in my Nexus 6P and I can see my phone on the adb devices.

Any help on Android Things is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you first take the board out of the box, it is only loaded with the `fastboot` bootloader. There is no Android software running on it until you complete the [flashing instructions](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/imx7d.html). Until this has been done, the ADB command will not work.

After you plug in the board, what do you see running the `fastboot devices` command? If the board is listed here, then the bootloader is active and it is ready to flash:

```
$ fastboot devices
1b2f21d4e1fe0129        fastboot
```

Execute the `flash-all` script provided with the downloaded image to get Android Things onto the board.